# How can I store marshaled data?

Tags: c++, com, idl

I have an rpc com interface which passes data from a service to a client. On the client side, I need to store this data temporarily and put it into a queue so that it can be processed later on the ui thread (this needs to be done on the ui thread because that is where the view and view model objects need to be created).

The structure is a bit complex and contains pointers to other structures and variable length strings.

Question - is there an easy way to grab the full "blob" of marshaled memory for stowing or do I need to duplicate the same structure and repack it myself so I can later process it on the ui thread? Currently this looks like duplicating the same structs but replacing LPCWSTR with CComBSTR etc etc which seems kind of dirty and wasteful to me...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Until you need to make sense of the data, you can just treat it as a sequence of bytes. The only thing that you need to know is just how much data you have. You can then do something like:

```
std::vector<unint8_t> buf;
buf.resize(length);
memcpy(&buf[0], source, length);
```

and then at a later point in time, assuming your vector is still around

```
memcpy(dest, &buf[0], buf.size());
```

The vector will get freed when it goes out of scope.

The only thing that can be a bit tricky may be getting the length. This might need some knowledge of the data sent but otherwise there is no need to unpack the data.

Answer (score 0):

You're supposed to marshal the data between your background thread and your UI thread (see [CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693316%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [CoGetInterfaceAndReleaseStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms691421%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for example). Passing a COM object between threads directly is illegal.

Using the above mentioned API's, you would generate the `IStream` object and queue the corresponding pointer. Then the UI thread would eventually recover the pointer, call the second API, and retrieve the marshalled copy of the object.

That all assumes that the data is in a COM object to begin with. If it's a blob copied over the wire by your COM object, then proper semantics dictate that when you requested the data from the COM object, you acquired ownership of it (and responsibility to release/delete it). Then just queue a pointer to the data as-is, and have the UI thread do the release/delete (How? I'm not sure; I have to look it up. Maybe CoTaskMemFree()?)

If it's a more bizarre scenario, please clarify what that is.